# Global variables in Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell, binding

I have this function:

```
map(\x -> l ++ [x]) "Show" where l = ""
```

I want the values of l to be saved at every step of the map function (e.g. I don't want to return `["S","h","o","w"]`, I want it to return `["S","Sh","Sho","Show"]`)

Can someone help me?

Comment: What you want is a running sum/accumulator, i.e. use `scanl`. For the literal question about global variables, [read a Haskell book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), because that's not how this works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're nearly there:

```
inits (x:xs) = map (\ys -> x:ys) ([]:inits xs)
inits [] = []
```

but note that you can rewrite `(\ys -> x:ys)` as `(x:)`, which puts `x` at the front of each list it encounters, giving

```
inits (x:xs) = map (x:) ([]:inits xs)
inits [] = []
```

This works because `map (x:) ([]:inits xs)` gives you `(x:[]) : map (x:) (inits xs)`, so everything in the list starts with `x`, and the first one is just `[x]`. That's true also of `inits xs`, so each gets one element longer.

### There's a standard function

As usual, you're not the first to want this, which is why the function is defined already in `Data.List`. All you need to do is add

```
import Data.List
```

to the top of the program and you get `inits` predefined.

### How is inits defined there?

Now if you look up hoogle for that, http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=inits you can click through to find

```
inits                   :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits xs                =  [] : case xs of
                                  []      -> []
                                  x : xs' -> map (x :) (inits xs')
```

which is almost exactly the same idea, but in a case statement, which moves the pattern matching to be internal to the function.

Notice that this is slightly different to what you wanted, because you get a `[]` at the front of your answer, but you could use `tail` to get rid of that.

```
myinits = tail.inits
```

### How can you find if there's already a function?

You wanted to turn a list into a list of lists. That should have type `[a]->[[a]]`. You can search for that on hoogle http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[a]+-%3E+[[a]] and it's the top answer (more generally it might be lower down and you'd have to browse a bit.

This works for a lot of standard functions, since hoogle indexes all of base for a start.

Comment: And if a have a function as the same of above but i want it to work for a data type how can i do it ?

Comment: map(\x -> if (isLetter x) then (update exp (Literal x) "") else Epsilon) "a+b+c+" where exp = Epsilon and I want the variable exp to update each time

Comment: @Edy That's really another question - please could you ask it separately, listing your code for your data type with `Epsilon` and `Literal` and all there for us to refer to.

Answer (score 2):

Use `scanl` :

```
Prelude> scanl (\a c -> a++[c]) "" "Show"
["","S","Sh","Sho","Show"]
```

An efficient version:

```
Prelude> map reverse . scanl (flip (:)) [] $ "Show"
["","S","Sh","Sho","Show"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Data.List.inits`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3ainits):

```
> tail $ inits "Show"
["S","Sh","Sho","Show"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just combine inits and tail functions from Prelude:

```
tail . inits $ "Show"
```